# Showing or hide line numbers at SSMS with shortcut?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

Is it possible to use a shortcut for the showing or hide the line numbers at the SSMS ?

I know its possible to go to the settings and to do it.
But is there really no shortcuts for it? If I see it right, I cant even sets shortcut keys keyboards setting for it.

Its would be very usefull, if available.

[image: See here]

Comment: **Show/Hide Line Numbers in SSMS**
Click Tools–>Options as highlighted in green color below.
In Options Dialog Box, Under Text Editor, in Transact-SQL, General –>Line Numbers . Enable the checkbox, If you want to Display/Show Line Numbers in SSMS. Disable the checkbox, If you want to Hide Line Numbers in SSMS.

Comment: I know it. That is not the answer to the question.

Comment: Like Stu said, there's no keyboard shortcut for this.  However, I'd really be interested in knowing WHY this is important to you.

Answer (score 32):

There is currently no such shortcut, but you could probably create a macro to accomplish it or use an extension that allows you to define shortcuts. The only native way to show/hide the line numbers is to do the following:

1. Click on Tools > Options
2. Click on Text Editor > Transact SQL
3. Check the "Line Numbers" box

[image: Click on Tools > Options]

[image: Go to Text Editor > Transact SQL > Check the "Line Numbers" box]

[image: Line numbers appear in the sidebar]

Answer (score 5):

No, according to the current documentation there is no keyboard shortcut to control line numbers, you enable or disable from the Options dialog (Text Editor > All Languages > General).

[See the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/manage-the-editor-and-view-mode?view=sql-server-ver15#displaying-line-numbers)

Comment: How to do a feature recommendation for ssms? Its an important shortcut.

Comment: See [feedback.azure.com](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/). Fwiw, I've never once needed a keyboard shortcut for this, line numbers are just enabled, period.

Comment: We need a shortcut.